# Запросы Sql Server сортировка по дате

Tags: sql-server

Нужно найти 3 самых крупных по количеству поставок товаров до 2013 года  и товар должен относятся к категории(HDD), так же нужно вывести дату поставки без учёта времени.И на той же базе отсортировать данные по дате и времени.

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT pr.provider, c.category, a.date, SUM(a.quantity*a.price) AS 'SUM'
FROM actions a
INNER JOIN products p ON a.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN providers ON a.provider_id = pr.id
INNER JOIN categories c ON product_id = c.id
WHERE c.category LIKE'HDD' -- не знаю что суда писать
GROUP BY pr.provider, c.category, date
ORDER BY [SUM] DESC
```

Просто по дате понятно, ORDER BY date и всё!
А, вот как вывести дату поставки без учёта времени и отсортировать данные по дате и времени не пойму.

Формат даты такой 2015-08-07 08:45:00

Comment: a.date - в формате дата и время? какая версия sql-server?

Comment: Ну первое решается просто, приводим колонку к типу date, который времени не содержит. т.е. и в списке выборки и в group by пишем `cast(a.date as date)`. А вот вторая задача в вашей формулировке не выполнима. Если мы группируем строки без учета времени, то скажем в строку '01.01.2018' попадут результаты всех строк с такой датой и эта строка на выходе будет только одна и что для нее означает "отсортировать со временем" не понятно, потому что никакого времени уже нет.

Comment: @Mike Имеется ввиду что база одна. `вывести дату поставки без учёта времени.` а, второе задание отсортировать ту же базу по дате и времени

Comment: @j.Atisto ну отсортировать по дате и времени просто `order by a.date`

Comment: @j.Atisto в один день может быть несколько поставок? если да, то что делать - считать каждую отдельно или суммарно за день?

Comment: @Mike Так имеется ввиду простая сортировка что ли? К стати попробовал сделать `CAST(a.date AS [date])` правильно сделал или нет? под date что имеется ввиду.

Comment: @ а, можно и так и так пример!

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis  вроде всё сортировать нужно. Но можно и отдельно написать пример.

Comment: можно использовать при условии, что поставки в один день не нужно объединять - `SELECT top 3 pr.provider, c.category, cast (a.date as date) date, a.quantity*a.price AS 'SUM'
FROM actions a
INNER JOIN products p ON a.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN providers ON a.provider_id = pr.id
INNER JOIN categories c ON product_id = c.id
WHERE c.category='HDD'
ORDER BY [SUM] DESC, a.date `

Comment: @j.Atisto Под date в cast понимается тип данных date и он не должен заключаться в квадратные скобки, так как это не название столбца

Comment: @Mike Понятно! Спасибо!

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis Спасибо! А, как найти 3 самых крупных по количеству поставок товаров до 2013 не знаешь?

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis То есть даты к примеру идут с 2010 до 2018 года, А, мне нужно только до 2013г.

Comment: добавить в where `and a.date<'20130101'`

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis Спасибо сейчас попробую!!!

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis Слушай , а не знаешь как сделать запрос, в результате которого выводится список наименований товаров, хотя бы один раз поступивших в 2016 году

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение обсуждено в комментариях:

```
SELECT top 3 pr.provider, c.category, cast (a.date as date) date, 
a.quantity*a.price AS 'SUM' 
FROM actions a INNER JOIN products p ON a.product_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN providers ON a.provider_id = pr.id 
INNER JOIN categories c ON product_id = c.id 
WHERE c.category='HDD' and a.date<'20130101' 
ORDER BY [SUM] DESC, a.date
```

Список наименований товаров, хотя бы один раз поступивших в 2016:

```
 SELECT distinct p.id
 FROM actions a INNER JOIN products p ON a.product_id = p.id 
 WHERE a.date>='20160101' and a.date<'20170101'
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!